# Pentaho Dashboard Render Too Slow

Tags: pentaho, dashboard, pentaho-cde

Currently I'm working with Pentaho CDE, I have more then 100 components in my dashboard.

My problem is, when i change something and save the dashboard, Save process take 1 to 2 mins .

From googling, I heard that by click on save button re-write all content. **Is there any way to speed up the save process** ?

And also, preview the saved dashboard takes 3 minutes to render in web browser. **How can i speed up the render performance**?

Dashboard likes below

[image]

By clicking Select Dashboard button will change the Component. Dashboard will be Sales,purchase, Invoice and etc.

Thanks in advance,

Dhina

Comment: WOW thats a lot of components, whats the use case? Can you share a pic?

Comment: @Codek I have updated screen shot, Please refer

Comment: Im surprised that is struggling to load, i've seen quite a few like that and usually they're nippy.  What browser? Are there any errors in the console?  If you look at the net traffic, what is the cause of the slowness, you should be able to see whether your queries are performing ok or not.

Answer (score 0):

This dashboard does not look like it has 100+ components.

However, I'm curious about the first drop down (top left): Select Dashboard. Does this redirect to a new dashboard or are you hiding/showing components in the same dashboard ?